# Django Responds code 500 no matter what

Tags: python, django

I have a method in Django where I get POST data from a mobile app and all I do is save it and send a Response. The problem is though the the data gets saved but no matter what the app receives the response code 500.

```
 <Response [500]>
```

code:

```
@csrf_exempt 
def store_recordings(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "In POST",request.POST
        driverName = request.POST['driverName']
        driverMobileNum = request.POST['driverMobileNum']
        customerMobileNum = request.POST['customerMobileNum']
        salesOrderNo = request.POST['salesOrderNo']
        callRecord = request.POST['callRecord']
        latitude = request.POST['latitude']
        longitude = request.POST['longitude']
        callStart = request.POST['callStart']
        callEnd = request.POST['callEnd']
        callDuration = request.POST['callDuration']
        callType = request.POST['callType']
        driverrecording = DriverRecording(driverName=driverName,driverMobileNum=driverMobileNum,customerMobileNum=customerMobileNum,salesOrderNo=salesOrderNo,callRecord=callRecord,latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude,callStart=callStart,callEnd=callEnd,callDuration=callDuration,callType=callType)
        save_or_not = driverrecording.save()
        driverexist = DriverNames.objects.all()
        new_driver_flag = False
        driverName_list = [each.driverName for each in driverexist] 
        driverName_list = list(set(driverName_list))
        if driverName in driverName_list:
            pass
        else:
            DriverNames(driverName=driverName,driverMobileNum=driverMobileNum).save()
        return HttpResponse(status=201)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

I am perplexed what is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: is there any traceback available from Django?

Comment: error log shows no error. I tried to print a a statement right before the `return HttpResponse(status=201)` and it did successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, one or more of those fields is not being sent, so you are getting a KeyError. If you set DEBUG to True you would see the traceback.

You should be using Django's forms framework, instead of directly accessing the POST data. That will validate the input and allow you to display any errors.

Comment: I took your advice used Django's Forms. The data gets saved but I get the same response 500.

Comment: Just Wondering, can it be something related to the apache server or mod_wsgi configuration ?